# Invite People to folder with Onedrive for Buisness RESTful API

Tags: onedrive

I'm using the onedrive RESTful API to integrate a webapp and share file between a group of people. I manage to correctly authenticate a user and get its access token, create folders and upload files.

The problem I'm having is finding a way to invite people to a folder. The closest documentation I have found is about permissions, where it talks about updating permissions (read, write, creating links) however I cant get a way to invite a specific user to a folder like its done directly in the One drive official webapp [OneDrive Invite people to folder img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04woo.png)

Answer (score 1):

We don't officially support adding permissions through OneDrive API yet. If you need to do this in a production environment right now you'd need to use the SharePoint REST API to add the user permissions.

In the near future we'll be adding an invite function to the OneDrive API. While we haven't released documentation on it yet, you can see the unofficial syntax for it by looking at the service metadata information for the consumer service (https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/$metadata). Of course, usage of this API would not be supported until it is documented on dev.onedrive.com though.

-Ryan